# java recursion a to user defined input

Tags: java, recursion

How do you stop recursion from printing A to lowercase letters?
 Expected output(
 input d returns abcd
 input D returns ABCD)

```
Public static void main(String[] args){
    printLettersForward('D');
    System.out.println();
    printLettersForward('d');
    System.out.println()
}


public static void printLettersForward(char c) {  

    if (c >= 'a'||c >= 'z') {
        printLettersForward((char) (c - 1));
        System.out.print(c+" ");    

    }else if(c >= 'A'||c >= 'Z') {
        printLettersForward((char) (c - 1));
        System.out.print(c+" ");    

    }else {
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

output:
A B C D

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d

let me know how to ask better questions.

Comment: `c >= 'a'||c >= 'z'` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are incorrect.

Fix as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printLettersForward('D');
    System.out.println();
    printLettersForward('d');
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printLettersForward(char c) {
    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
        printLettersForward((char) (c - 1));
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    } else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
        printLettersForward((char) (c - 1));
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```